# jquery-1.10.2.js:1472 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: label[for='team[]'], label[for='team[]'] *, #team[]-error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using multiselect js plugin in select element and jquery validate plugin to validate form elements.

I know this is because of '`[]`' in select element `name` attribute, that is causing this error, but I want to enable multiple selections.

When I remove '`[]`', it is working fine..

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="internal_team">Team <span class="input-required">*</span></label>
         <div class="col-sm-7">
              <select name="team[]" class="form-control multiselect-ui" multiple>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              </select>
         </div>
</div>
```

Here's my jquery validate:

```
rules: 
{
   "team[]": "required"
},
messages:
{
     "team[]": "Please select team",
}
```

How do I solve this issue??
Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have to escape the `[]` like `#team\[\]-error`

Comment: You **cannot** have an empty array for naming multiple elements with the jQuery Validate plugin.  You would have to use an index... `team[0]`, `team[1]`, `team[2]`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried assigning an id to select tag and retrieving values with **multiselect** method?

```
<select name="team[]" class="form-control multiselect-ui" id="team" multiple="multiple">

$('#team').multiSelect()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the `[]` because jQuery thinks its an attribute selector.

`$("label[for='team[]'], label[for='team[]'] *, #team[]-error")`

Should be

`$("label[for='team[]'], label[for='team[]'] *, #team\\[\\]-error")`

**demo**

```js
$("label[for='team[]'], label[for='team[]'] *, #team\\[\\]-error")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but I guess this expression is generated by plugin itself.. How do I take control over it?

Comment: why not remove `[]` from `name="team[]"`

Comment: then it would not store multiple selected options..

Comment: @Azima can you create a snippet that displays the problem?